# Use jQuery UI with prototype

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I must use jquery, but the site contains prototype elements, and jquery UI tabs not working:
How jQuery.noConflict(); works in this code?
    
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using jQuery.noConflict(), you have to use jQuery() instead of $() when using jQuery functions. Assuming that the code you provided is jQuery-based, it has to look the following:

```
jQuery(function() { jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs(); });
```